# SQL inclusion and exclusion

Tags: mysql, sql

The property listing table has a listing id (lid) and owner id (cid).

The hasA, hasB, hasC tables are descriptors of the property. hasA holds Active Codes like: For Sale, For Rent etc. hasB holds Status Codes like: New Price, Just Listed, Under Contract etc. hasC holds Description Codes like: Single Family, Land, Farm, Waterfront, Mountain View, Log, etc.

I do not foresee the use of exclusion in the hasA table but I do need it in the hasB and hasC tables.

In this example I will just reference the numbers. Everything can be copied to sqlfiddle.

```
create table listings (
  lid integer, 
  cid integer 
);

create table hasA (
  lid integer,
  cid integer,
  id integer
 );

create table hasB (
  lid integer,
  cid integer,
  id integer
 );

create table hasC (
  lid integer,
  cid integer,
  id integer
 );


insert into listings values
(901,4),(902,4),(903,4),(904,4),(905,4),(906,4),(907,4),(908,5);

insert into hasA values
(901,4,333),(902,4,333),(903,4,333),(904,4,333),(905,4,333),(906,4,333),(907,4,444),(908,5,333);

insert into hasB values
(901,4,700),(901,4,707),(902,4,702),(902,4,701),(903,4,701),(904,4,708),(905,4,708);

insert into hasC values
(901,4,2000),(901,4,2001),(902,4,2000),(902,4,2003),(903,4,2000),(903,4,2001),(904,4,2015);
```

I need help building TWO queries. Possibly this has been answered but I did look through the existing solutions and was unable to apply other solutions to my problem. My SQL is basic.

In the first query I am including all listings that have 333 in hasA, and 2001 in hasC. Using IN () has always worked fine for my results. Result set: 901, 903.

```
select a.lid 
  from listings a, hasA b, hasC c 
 where a.lid = b.lid 
   and a.lid = c.lid 
   and a.cid = b.cid 
   and a.cid = c.cid 
   and b.id in (333) 
   and c.id in (2001);
```

Now I am trying to get all the listings where hasC cannot include 2001. Based on visual deduction the desired result set is: 902, 904, 905, 906. My use of  NOT IN() below does not work.

```
select a.lid 
  from listings a, hasA b, hasC c 
 where a.lid = b.lid 
   and a.lid = c.lid 
   and a.cid = b.cid 
   and a.cid = c.cid 
   and b.id in (333) 
   and c.id not in (2001);
```

The next examples involve the same logic but includes the hasB and hasC table.

Straight forward inclusion works fine and gives result set: 903

```
select a.lid 
  from listings a, hasA b, hasB c, hasC d 
 where a.lid = b.lid 
   and a.lid = c.lid 
   and a.lid = d.lid 
   and a.cid = b.cid 
   and a.cid = c.cid 
   and a.cid = d.cid 
   and b.id in (333) 
   and c.id in (701) 
   and d.id in (2001)
```

Now I am trying to get all the listings where hasC cannot include 2001. Based on visual deduction the desired result set is: 902. My use of  NOT IN() below does not work.

```
select a.lid 
  from listings a, hasA b, hasB c, hasC d 
 where a.lid = b.lid 
   and a.lid = c.lid 
   and a.lid = d.lid 
   and a.cid = b.cid 
   and a.cid = c.cid 
   and a.cid = d.cid 
   and b.id in (333) 
   and c.id in (701) 
   and d.id not in (2001)
```

If my desired result set based on visual deduction is incorrect, please correct this.

Comment: Are you asking for one query or a few? It's hard to tell what you're after. You mention the desired result being 902 and 903 at one point, then you say 903 is good, then that the desired result is 904. Can you clarify what the desired result is, and why?

Comment: I'm asking for 2 queries. I went over the desired result sets again by visually looking at the table contents and feel they are correct now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are dealing with "set-within-sets" queries.  I like `group by` and `having` for solving this problem, precisely because it is very flexible.

The following is for your last query:

```
select a.lid
from listings a left join
     hasA b
     on a.lid = b.lid left join
     hasB c
     on a.cid = c.cid left join
     hasC d
     on a.lid = d.lid
group by a.lid
having sum(b.id in (333)) > 0 and
       sum(c.id in (701)) > 0 and
       coalesce(sum(d.id in (2001)), 0) = 0;
```

Each condition in the `having` clause corresponds to one of the conditions.  The `> 0` means that the condition is found in the listings.  The `= 0` means that it is not.

The SQL Fiddle is [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1da95/4).

In your case, because the values are coming from different tables, you can also use `exists` and `not exists`:

```
select a.*
from listings a
where exists (select 1 from hasA b where a.lid = b.lid and b.id in (333)) and
      exists (select 1 from hasB c where a.cid = c.cid and c.id in (701)) and
      not exists (select 1 from hasC d where a.lid = d.lid and d.id in (2001));
```

With appropriate indexes, this would probably be faster in MySQL.

Comment: The first query returns 902 and 903. The second query (if you add the alias for the hasc table (d)) returns 902, 904, 905, 906.

Comment: @BrianDeMilia . . . Excellent observation.  Not only are `left join`s required because some of the tables are missing the corresponding `id`s, but the case of `= 0` may occur when there are no matches and the `sum()` is `NULL` rather than `0`.

Comment: Both of these queries give 902,904,905,906 but I feel the correct result set should be 902. Criteria, listing with cid=4, must have a 333 record in hasA, must have 701 in hasB and cannot have 2001 in hasC.

Comment: A cleaned up version now gives the expected result set of: 902

select a.*
from listings a
where exists (select 1 from hasA b where a.lid = b.lid and b.cid = 4 and b.id in (333)) and
      exists (select 1 from hasB c where a.lid = c.lid and c.cid = 4 and c.id in (701)) and
      not exists (select 1 from hasC d where a.lid = d.lid and d.cid=4 and d.id in (2001));